# Excel 2016 Bing Map add-in

Tags: excel, bing-maps

I have a worksheet with Lat and Long data and I'm able to display a bing map with the Lat Long data as stops. How can I make those stops display as Stop 1, Stop 2, etc. and a line showing the route from Stop 1 to Stop 2, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bing maps add-in for Excel will just plot points for you, it won't calculate and display routes. If you want to display routes, you'll need to use the Bing Maps SDK here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712542.aspx

if you're targeting a web application

or the UWP map control here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/

if you're targeting a windows application.

If you just want to show users a simple multi-stop route, you can use this API to launch the map application and show the routes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app